# How to constrain a textview to the bottom of another textview with the ConstrainLayout being in a CardView

Tags: android, user-interface

[Text1 really want to go out of bound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU3fY.png)

I want text1 to be on top of text2 and both of them to be in the vertical center of the cardView

I have tried a bunch of permutation of constrains, adding and removing padding and all of them either ends up with text1 being out of bound or text1 and text2 merged together.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/material_dynamic_neutral30"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text2"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text3"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/text4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="text4"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your code output](https://imgur.com/jJWkFa5)

I tried your exact code and it's working fine for me, probably your XML viewer is not displaying the correct views. Try to do the following and see if they make a change

1. Clean project
2. Rebuild project
3. Sync project with gradle files

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the use of [`chains`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#constrain-chain).

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" 
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't work text1 still out of bound

Comment: @AssPlayer You mean in the preview nothing changed or when you install it on a device it's still wrong? (Preview sometimes gets stuck so you have to Force Refresh layout)

Comment: Damn, that is the problem. I restarted android studio and its fixed, cant believe i spend hours on this. Thank you so much